# Some results of suprimum and infimum.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ and $B $ be non empty subset of non negative reals, then we have $$sup(AB)=sup(A)sup(B)$$ and if  $A$ and $B $ are non empty subset of reals, then $$sup(AB) \geq sup(A)sup(B)$$ My question is that is the same type of results are true for infimum or not? like $$inf(AB)=inf(A)inf(B)$$ for non empty subset of non negative reals and $$inf(AB) \geq inf(A)inf(B)~ or ~inf(AB) \leq inf(A)inf(B)$$ for arbitrary non empty subsets of reals.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? You're supposed to do some own effort before posting questions, showing what you've tried would prove that you've done that.

Comment: i tried to find counterexamples...but did not get

Comment: Have you proved the first two statements for example? You should be able to use the similar techniques there.

Comment: do you mean the same is also true for infimum?

Comment: Yes, use the same technique as you would use for proving the statements for supremum. You suppose that you have a proof for the statements regarding the supremum. Don't you?

Comment: You might consider $A=B=[-1,1]$.